# Convert json String in Panda dataframe

Tags: json, pandas

I have a Json string, that contains a `key: value`  pair with a very long value.
It looks like this:

```js
{'Content': 'Jahr;Jahr;Jahr;Jahr;Jahr;Jahr;Jahr;Jahr;Jahr;Jahr;Jahr;Jahr;Jahr;Jahr;Jahr\n;;;;2018;2018;2018;2018;2019;2019;2019;2019;2020;2020;2020;2020;2021;2021;2021\n;;;;Quartale;Quartale;Quartale;Quartale;Quartale;Quartale;Quartale;Quartale;Quartale;Quartale;Quartale;Quartale;Quartale;Quartale;Quartale\n;;;;1. Quartal;2. Quartal;3. Quartal;4. Quartal;1. Quartal;2. Quartal;3. Quartal;4. Quartal;1. Quartal;2. Quartal;3. Quartal;4. Quartal;1. Quartal;2. Quartal;3. Quartal\nFrüheres Bundesgebiet;Energie- und Wasserversorgung;Index d.tarifl. Monatsverdienste ohne Sonderzahl.;2020=100;93,5;93,9;95,3;96,0;96,3;98,5;98,7;99,0;99,3;100,1;100,3;100,3;100,6;102,0;102,1\nNeue Länder;Energie- und Wasserversorgung;Index d.tarifl. Monatsverdienste ohne Sonderzahl.;2020=100;94,9;94,9;95,5;96,1;96,4;98,8;98,9;98,9;99,1;99,5;100,5;100,9;101,0;101,8;102,6\n'}
```

I would usually convert the content of the long Value into a dataframe (normalize it) to make it look like this:
[image]

But I have no idea how to convert this long string into a table - shape.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You'll need to provide a sample output dataframe, and rules for how it should look, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can do with your sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = {'Content': 'GENESIS...\n'}
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(d['Content']), skiprows=1, skipfooter=4,
                 header=None, sep=';', engine='python').T
df = df.ffill().loc[lambda x: x[4].notna()]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                                  0                         1                                                2     3     4         5           6      7
4   Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2018  Quartale  1. Quartal   93,5
5   Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2018  Quartale  2. Quartal   93,9
6   Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2018  Quartale  3. Quartal   95,3
7   Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2018  Quartale  4. Quartal   96,0
8   Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2019  Quartale  1. Quartal   96,3
9   Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2019  Quartale  2. Quartal   98,5
10  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2019  Quartale  3. Quartal   98,7
11  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2019  Quartale  4. Quartal   99,0
12  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2020  Quartale  1. Quartal   99,3
13  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2020  Quartale  2. Quartal  100,1
14  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2020  Quartale  3. Quartal  100,3
15  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2020  Quartale  4. Quartal  100,3
16  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2021  Quartale  1. Quartal  100,6
17  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2021  Quartale  2. Quartal  102,0
18  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Zeitreihe aus 62221BV002  Vj. Index der Tarifverdienste und Arbeitszeiten  Jahr  2021  Quartale  3. Quartal  102,1
```